# Bootstrapping on R - resampling for a stratfied sample

Tags: r, statistics, sampling, resampling

I have a survey data set and would like to bootstrap on R so that values from each strata are selected on a probability that represents their strata size in the overall population. I have tried various methods onthe boot() package and I am not sure if I am getting the results im looking for. For example when using the weights argument after defining each strata weight, I believe this is just creating a weighted mean for my bootstrap rather than stratified resampling. I am not sure which sim() option I need or what the strata() option does. Please help!

```
sample_mean = function(value,indices){return(mean(value[indices]))}
> results=boot(value,sample_mean,1000,weights = Weight)
```

Comment: Why not just use sample with prob argument?

Comment: Have you tried using the `strata` argument in `boot()`?

Comment: Hi what do I need to input into the strata argument, thanks

Comment: If `value` is a *dataset* then `value(tar[indices])` is not valid R code. It is using `value` as if it were a *function*.

Comment: Hi Joel. You put in the column or vector of labels (factor or integer) that describes the strata of data. These should be the same length as `value`. The draws will be proportional to the size of the strata automatically.

Comment: Hi sorry yes I changed the name of my data set to value to hide the real name and made an error in editing the code - I have updated this now.

Comment: Stephen I do not want the draws to be proportional to the strata size in sample data, I want them to be propotional to the strata in the overall population of interest

Comment: I believe what I am looking for is importance weights bootstrap but I am not sure how this can be done within the boot package

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, for the sake of reproducibility, you have

```
my_df <- data.frame(x=1:9, stratum=rep(1:3, each=3))
my_df
#   x stratum
# 1 1       1
# 2 2       1
# 3 3       1
# 4 4       2
# 5 5       2
# 6 6       2
# 7 7       3
# 8 8       3
# 9 9       3
```

and you have weights associated with strata `wts <- c(4,2,1)` - note, these don't necessarily need to add to 1.

You can bootstrap "by hand", with a call like

```
N_boot <- 10000
boot_mns <- rep(NA, N_boot)
for(i in 1:N_boot) {
   B <- sample(my_df$x, prob=wts[my_df$stratum])  
                 # or prob=wts[as.numeric(as.factor(my_df$stratum))] as needed
   boot_mns[i] <- mean(B)
}
```

Probably better form to do it with the `boot` package, but this is pretty explicit in what's going on.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. Do you know how it can be done within the boot package?